# How to increment database row by 1 for every time a link is clicked?

Tags: python, html, django, database, django-models

Currently every time I click on a product link on the website the entire database column "views" increases by 1 where as I need it so that just the row increases by 1. The link opens in an external website. The link is opened by clicking on the product image. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Models.py

```
class T_shirt(models.Model):
    Images = models.ImageField()
    Titles = models.CharField(max_length=250, primary_key=True)
    Prices = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Link = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Website = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Brand = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def t_detail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        T_shirt.objects.update(views=F('views') + 1)

    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        owner_obj = T_shirt.objects.filter(Titles__icontains=q)
    else:
        owner_obj = T_shirt.objects.all()

    p = Paginator(owner_obj, 20)

    page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        page = p.page(page_num)

    except EmptyPage:

        page = p.page(1)


    return render(request, 'tshirtshtml.html', {"owner_obj": page})
```

html

```
<ul class="products">
{% for v in owner_obj %}
    <div class="container">
    <form method="POST" type="submit">
        <button style="border: none;">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <a href="{{ v.Link }}" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <img src="{{ v.Images }}" width="150" height="150">
    </a>
        </button>

    </form>

    <figcaption>  {{ v.Titles }} </figcaption>
    <figcaption> <b>{{ v.Prices }}</b></figcaption>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Updated Code

```
def t_detail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        T_shirt.objects.filter(Titles=request.POST.get('tshirt_id')).update(views=F('views') + 1)

    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        owner_obj = T_shirt.objects.filter(Titles__icontains=q)
    else:
        owner_obj = T_shirt.objects.all()

    p = Paginator(owner_obj, 20)

    page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        page = p.page(page_num)

    except EmptyPage:

        page = p.page(1)

    return render(request, 'tshirtshtml.html', {"owner_obj": page})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need some identifier to fetch that particular row from db, right now you are updating all the rows with this logic:

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        T_shirt.objects.update(views=F('views') + 1)
```

for the current implementation, since you are using forms, you can add a hidden element inside the forms like:

```
<form method="POST" type="submit">
<button style="border: none;">
    {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="hidden" name="tshirt_id" value="{{ v.id }}" />
    <a href="{{ v.Link }}" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <img src="{{ v.Images }}" width="150" height="150">
    </a>
        </button>
   </form>
```

then change your view to get `tshirt_id` from request and update that row

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        T_shirt.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('tshirt_id')).update(views=F('views') + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks bud. For some reason every time the view column is updated on the row. The row is moved to the bottom of the table. I think the index changes to 0. Do you know how to keep it in the same position in the table?

Comment: Yeah so the when an items link gets clicked it updates the table but moves the row to a random location in the table. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: what do you mean by random position? how are you checking the position on the row?

Comment: So when the image of the product is clicked the views column gets updated by 1 but the entire row moves to a different position in the table. For example, the first product is at the top of the table but when clicked the row updates the views column by 1 but sends the row to the 21st row of the table. How do you keep the rows in the same position on the table after doing an update to the row?

Comment: I'm checking the position of the row in pgadmin 4. I have updated my views.py above

Comment: try to use `order_by('id')` to order your queryset.